# How can i do calculations on Textview setText Android

Tags: android, loops, textview, calculator

How can i add the value of n with 2 ?, ie., `n+2` the textview output should be 4 .

```
int n=2;
private void tvm() {
            if (n<=maxCount) {
                n++;
                textview.setText("Counter:"+ n+2);                 
}
```

Comment: output =4?? you are incrementing it before setting the text value, and then adding 2. what o/p are you getting now?

Comment: If you want output as 4 then first you need to set value in textview then increment nth value as i mentioned in my answer.

Comment: @ Kiran what u want plz explain more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int n=2;
private void tvm() {
            if (n<=maxCount) {            
                textview.setText("Counter:"+ String.valueOf( n+2));   
                  n++;              
}
```

Comment: In this case output is 5 not 4 as Sai Kiran wants !

Comment: comment out the post increment in n.

Answer (score 3):

Just you need to give the priority by giving brackets like the same shown in the above answers.Hope now it will be working fine.

```
tv.setText("Text you enter: "+ (a + b));
```

output: "Text you enter: `c`"

where `c =a + b`

Answer (score 1):

change your code to

```
textview.setText("Counter:"+ (n+2));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want output as 4 then first you need to set value to textView then incrment n value.

```
if (n<=maxCount) 
{
    text.setText("Counter:"+ (n+2));
    n++;
}
```

**Output :**  Counter:4